# How to eliminate duplicate items while adding them to their own structure

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionary items, with each dictionary containing a list of presentation items. The sample dictionaries below are a small prototype of my real data set.
I need to remove duplicate presentations based on day (one presentation per day) and store them in a new dictionary with the same structure within the existing list.

So starting with:

```
[
  {
    "time": "04:00-20:59",
    "category": 1,
    "presentations": [
      {
        "presentation": "ABC",
        "day": 7,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "DEF",
        "day": 7,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "GHI",
        "day": 8,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "JKL",
         "day": 8,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "MNO",
        "day": 9,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "PQR",
         "day": 9,
      },
      {
        "presentation": "STU",
        "day": 9,
      }
    ]
  } #only one dictionary item in the list for simplicity
]
```

The end result should be three dictionaries containing lists of presentations where there is one presentation for a given day:

```
[
  {
    "time": "04:00-20:59",
    "category": 1,
    "presentations": [
      {
        "presentation": "ABC",
        "day": 7
      },
      {
        "presentation": "DEF",
        "day": 8
      },

      {
        "presentation": "GHI",
        "day": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "time": "04:00-20:59",
    "category": 1,
    "presentations": [
      {
        "presentation": "JKL",
        "day": 7
      },
      {
        "presentation": "MNO",
        "day": 8
      },

      {
        "presentation": "PQR",
        "day": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "time": "04:00-20:59",
    "category": 1,
    "presentations": [
      {
        "presentation": "STU",
        "day": 9
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to go about removing these duplicates (based on day) while adding them to their own dictionary.

Comment: You need to remove duplicates or assign duplicates new days (and if so, based on what criteria?)?

Comment: @K-man I need to remove duplicate presentations from the original list if there is more than one presentation for a given day. For example, there are 3 presentations on day 9 in the original list, so there needs to be 3 separate lists containing a presentation for day 9.